# Can I change series array completely in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a requirement where I need to change series array completely in the chart,

I have 2 legends in my chart, I wish to load a chart with one disabled legend, that's working fine, 
now when the user clicks on the disabled legend corresponding data should be added automatically to the chart, 
I tried same with chart.series.addSeries(), but that is giving different issues, as the new data which is to be added is not only after the first legend but it's in between those legends

[chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/926xO.png)
For eg: chart loads, with just grey legends, orange is hidden or is not added at all, on clicking on the orange colour legend I want to add this data to that chart, Please check the chart in the image
 is there any way to replace series array completely.

Something like

```
chart.update({
    series:newSeriesArray
});
```

I am using the bar chart from highchart.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> I have 2 legends in my chart

Do you have a separate legend for each series or do you mean legend item for each series?

Highcharts provide a possibility to set data to particular series - [series.setData()](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#setData) method. So when a chart is initialized you can create empty series (series with name, color etc but without data array) with property `visible: false`, then your series will be hidden and legend item disabled:

```
  {
    name: 'Year 2016',
    data: [],
    visible: false
  }
```

When user clicks legend item [plotOptions.series.events.legendItemClick](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.events.legendItemClick) function will be invoked (if defined). In this function, you can set data to this particular series using `series.setData()` as mentioned above:

```
  plotOptions: {
    bar: {
      events: {
        legendItemClick: function() {
          if (!this.data.length) {
            this.setData([665, 234, 2344, 123, 23])
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/wchmiel/uLfcknsb/

Comment: Thanks, for your help, it was really Useful.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it is a stacked bar chart. 
I have 2 legends for the chart. For eg: 2018 - orange & 2017 - grey
and series values is 
series = [{
 name : '2018', 
 data : []
 color: 'orange' 
}, {
 name : '2018', 
 data : []
 color: 'orange' 
}, {
 name : '2017', 
 data : []
 color: 'grey' 
}, {
 name : '2018', 
 data : []
 color: 'orange' 
}, {
 name : '2017', 
 data : []
 color: 'grey' 
}, {
 name : '2018', 
 data : []
 color: 'orange' 
}]

Comment: Could you send me jsfiddle demo of your chart?